# How can I make wifi automatically go on when my G1 boots up

Tags: wi-fi, htc-dream

I've got CM6 on it, and every once in a while the power goes out, the battery eventually dies, the power comes back and it boots up but no wifi. I have the thing in a faraway place and I get to it via ssh, so it's annoying to have to go manually turn on wifi when it reboots.

Is there a script somewhere I can run in userinit.sh that will turn on wifi?

Comment: Do you have Flight Mode on, by any chance?

Comment: yes I do. I don't wanna burn the battery up as I have no service on that phone.

Comment: Yeah, I get annoyed by the same behavior on my (mostly stock) Vibrant.  Interesting that they didn't change it in CM.

Answer (score 1):

There's an APP to workaround that issue, [Wifi Fixer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.wahtod.wififixer) available for Free from Google Play Store:

> Wifi Fixer is a low-resource background Service that maintains your wifi connection automatically and works around several bugs in Android wifi.

Comment: herm, it seems to do everything but the one thing I want: turn on wifi automatically upon reboot. Or am I missing a setting somewhere?

Comment: @stu I Can't test the APP right now, but if you can't find an option to make it run at system startup, you can install a [Startup Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=imoblife.startupmanager&hl=en), to add and enable it to start with system boot.

Comment: oh, the app runs at startup, I was all excited that my dreams may have come true, but it never turned on the wifi.

Comment: @stu You may also have some other app installed that prevents the WiFi from connecting... I've got a battery saver that does just that!